# AWS AppSync getting the count of another table (for example counting the likes of a post)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have the following AWS AppSync/Amplify model

```
type Event @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  ticketsSold: Int!
  moneySum: Int!
}
```

The `ticketsSold` property must reflect the count of `orders` with `eventId = X`. `moneySum` must represent a SUM of all the orders ticket price with `eventId = X`.

There are 2 options (or more?) to consider:

1. With every `putItem` (createOrder mutation), update the correct `event` row with the new count/sum
2. Do a query/scan of all the orders with `eventId = X` via an AWS Lambda resolver

There are some pro's and con's with each of the options. With option 1 there is the possibility to get out of sync if multiple people order at the same time (transactions?). With option 2 there is the drawback that scanning is very expensive & slow...

The events are shown on the home page of a ReactJS app with the `ticketsSold` and `moneySum` shown as a preview and on the detail so it will get fetched "a lot".

Suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 1 using streams from your ticket DB into a lambda that updates some table with the aggregated info. It's going to be pretty fast and way cleaner than endless scans. I use this to aggregate lambda usage for users, logging lambda runtime into a table that can be instantly queried for the total. Works great.

Comment: How do you handle transactions? As multiple triggers can be executed at the same time? Firebase has transactions for instance, not sure how to do this with AWS services?

Comment: I don't see transactions would be an issue The appropriate table streams (tickets?) reflect the valid data you care about. Depending on your scenario you can have insert/modify/remove events handled by the aggregating lambda. The lambda can receive up to 1000 stream records in a single batch.